# Value does not fall within the expected range exception when redirecting to a different URL

Tags: c#, sitecore, httpresponse, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect to a different URL in case that the original URL is not found, but there is a mapping to a different URL available and I need to redirect to.

```cs
public class RedirectRequestHandler:ExecuteRequest
{
    private string _host { get; set; }
    private HttpContext _context { get; set; }
    public RedirectRequestHandler()
    {
        _context = HttpContext.Current;
        _host = _context.Request.Url.Host;
    }

    protected override void RedirectOnItemNotFound(string url)
    {
        Database siteCoreContext = Context.Database;
        try
        {
            Uri redirectedUrl;
            if (GetRedirectedUrl($"{_host}{_context.Request.RawUrl}",out redirectedUrl))
            {
                 var uri = redirectedUrl.AbsoluteUri;
                _context.Response.RedirectPermanent(uri);
            }              

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            base.RedirectOnItemNotFound(url);
        }

        _context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

The code throws an exception:

```
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
  at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.SendStatus(Int32 statusCode, Int32 subStatusCode, String statusDescription)
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.UpdateNativeResponse(Boolean sendHeaders)
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
  at WolfGreenfield.Classes.RedirectRequestHandler.RedirectOnItemNotFound(String url) in C:\Code\wgf-website\src\website\classes\RedirectRequestHandler.cs:line 31
```

and the message is that:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

I am not sure how I can resolve this? I simply want to redirect to a different page and send a 301 HTTP status code back to the browser.

Comment: Pretty sure you are supposed to give the new Location as part of the Location of a 301 Error, not automatically redirect. You either redirect or give a HTTP error, not both. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I used the same context (_context) throughout my code. Also, to redirect permanently, I used the following code:

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
Item item = GetItemFromUrl(redirectedUrl);    
context.Response.RedirectPermanent(LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item),true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are also facing the above issue and the suggested solution doesn't work for you and your Sitecore installation is still showing above error, I would suggest checking the residual files that have been created by that failed Sitecore installation and try to restart your website there in the IIS, if you are able to see above index error, then try with another instance name probably with another identifier.

In my machine, it was getting created like "sc901.dev..xconnect" and "sc901.dev..sc.local"
I just edited my install script to change the instance name.